# java.net.MalformedUrlException in itunes producer

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes, itunes-store, producer

I am trying to publish an ePub on iTunes producer. The ePub file passes validation in `epubcheck` tool.

I am receiving the following error while submitting the epub:

> Error: Internal error: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: bundle schema/20/rng/container.rng" at Book/BookAssets

All my links have HTTP protocol specified without any typos.

I wish to publish on iTunes at the earliest. Not sure where this issue is coming from.

Answer (score 5):

Go to Preferences - Advanced - uncheck Aspera and try again. It worked for me.

Comment: And restart Producer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: A year later - did not work for me. My original inclination was to update Java, but don't want to mess up Eclipse. Going to try iBooks Author.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was simply to remove underscores from filenames from xhtml files inside the ebook. Sounds strange but this solved the problem for me.